# Get value from ajax loaded page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

How can I get the values from the form that is placed in add.php? add.php is a simple file with only one form. Submitting will be done by the following code:

```
var $addGroup = $('<div></div>')
.load('../view/group/add.php')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Aanmaken groep",
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            var $groupname = $('#name').val();
            alert($groupname);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

I need to get the value $groupname from the field with id 'name'. The current value is undefinied.

Comment: You need to use [`$_GET`, `$_POST`](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: You should submit that as an answer to your question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

`$.post('../control/group/add.php', $('#addGroupForm').serialize());`

was the solution of course, don't know why I didn't try that